# Finding highest number of votes and matching to array of string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to match a candidate name with candidate votes and display the highest vote along with the candidate name.

As in how to match the two arrays I have.

I know I'm missing something but what? I've only started learing C# at home.

```
namespace NumberOfVotes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size, minVotes;
            int[] numOfCandidates;
            int[] numOfVotes;
            double avgMarks;

            string[] candidateName;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of candidates");
            size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            numOfCandidates = new int[size];
            candidateName = new string[size];
            numOfVotes = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfCandidates.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Candidate Name");
                candidateName[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter number of votes thus far");
                numOfVotes[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int max = numOfVotes.Max();          
            avgMarks = numOfVotes.Average();
            minVotes = numOfVotes.Min();

            Console.WriteLine("Average votes: {0}", avgMarks);
            Console.WriteLine("Min number of votes is: {0}", minVotes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the issue? which line? what's not working?

Comment: Figure out the solution in your head, and then worry about how to accomplish it in C#. If you don't know the solution in your head, then it doesn't have much to do with C# ;)

Comment: You know what the maximum number of votes was. Why not loop through your `numOfVotes` array and every time you find an entry equal to the max value, you access the member name from the same position of the `candidateName` array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# find highest array value and index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Comment: Harry, the code itself is working but I want to be able to writeline the candidate name and his/her number of votes

Comment: This isn't CodeReview, but a view things: You don't need `numOfCandidates`. You only use it once to get its length, but you already know that, so you can change your `for` loop to `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`. Also, `candidateName` and `numOfVotes` are completely separate arrays which are only very loosely connected by the index. Connected data should usually be put together in a `class`. But you basically only want to connect a string (the name of the candidate) to a value (the number of votes). So maybe a `Dictionary<string, int>` is all you need.

Comment: @RobGleeson You better use  Array.IndexOf() to get the index of the array having highest vote. You may check my answer.

Comment: Have you tried all the solutions presented in the answers?

Comment: The "drawback" with a dictionary is, that you cannot have two candidates with the exact same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these kind of things you can do with thinking about it with your head. StackOverflow isn't a website to post your problem if you're stuck, only if the problem you have needs a solution which can help other people.

This would work(most straightfoward approach to me):

```
int maxIndex = -1;
int max = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfCandidates.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Candidate Name");
    candidateName[i] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of votes thus far");
    int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // <-- unsafe

    // just check it every time, if the number is greater than the previous maximum, update it.
    if (num > max)
    {
       max = num;
       maxIndex = i;
    }

    numOfVotes[i] = num;
}

Console.WriteLine("Candidate {0}, with {1} votes, has the most votes", candidateName[maxIndex], max);
```

However, if you want more things to calculate (like who has the least votes) without doing these kind of things, you should use a `Dictionary<string, int>`. That's a string associated with a number, a name associated with votes.

(More info about that here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var candidates = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of candidates");
    var size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Candidate Name");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of votes thus far");
        var votes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        candidates.Add(name, votes);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Average votes: {0}", candidates.Average(entry => entry.Value));
    Console.WriteLine("Min number of votes is: {0}", candidates.Min(entry => entry.Value));
}
```

Comment: I think OPs implementation points more in the direction of a simple `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: Yes, and with `var winner = candidates.OrderByDescending(c => c.Value).First(); Console.WriteLine("Winner is {0} with {1} votes.", winner.Key, winner.Value);` you'd also get the candidate with the most votes. Ties will be a bit more complicated to handle.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem, as it is, is to do something like this:

```
int indexOfWinner = Array.IndexOf(numOfVotes, numOfVotes.Max());
string winner = candidateName[indexOfWinner];
```

I don't know how far along in your C# and programming education you are (OOP and suchlike), so a couple of points you may find obvious or not:

- you should use generic collections and not primitive arrays (`List<>` in this case).
- you should encapsulate all this into a class.

This is how I would do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Candidates c = new Candidates("foo", "bar", "baz");
        Random rand = new Random();
        c.addVote(0, rand.Next(100));
        c.addVote(1, rand.Next(100));
        c.addVote(2, rand.Next(100));

        Console.WriteLine(c.getWinner());

        Console.WriteLine("number of votes:");
        Console.WriteLine(c[0] + ": " + c[0].numberOfVotes);
        Console.WriteLine(c[1] + ": " + c[1].numberOfVotes);
        Console.WriteLine(c[2] + ": " + c[2].numberOfVotes);
    }
}

class Candidates
{
    private List<Candidate> candidates;

    public Candidate this[string name] {
        get {
            return candidates.First(v => v.name == name);
        }
    }
    public Candidate this[int index] {
        get {
            return candidates[index];
        }
    }

    public Candidates(string firstCandidate, params string[] candidates) { //this is done to disable an empty constructor call
                                                                           //and also allow multiple candidates
        this.candidates = new List<Candidate>(candidates.Length);
        this.candidates.Add(new Candidate(firstCandidate));
        foreach(var c in candidates) {
            this.candidates.Add(new Candidate(c));
        }
    }

    public void addVote(int candidateNumber, int numberOfVotes = 1) {
        candidates[candidateNumber].numberOfVotes += numberOfVotes;
    }

    public Candidate getWinner() {
        candidates.Sort((candidate1, candidate2) => candidate2.numberOfVotes.CompareTo(candidate1.numberOfVotes));
        return candidates[0];
    }
}

class Candidate
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public int numberOfVotes { get; set; }

    public Candidate(string name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfVotes = 0;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use dictionary instead, but if you want to use array, here's how to do it :

```
avgMarks = numOfVotes.Average();

int avgIndex = numOfVotes.ToList().IndexOf(avgMarks);

Console.WriteLine("Average votes: {0} Candidate Names: {1}", avgMarks, candidateName[avgIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works fine. What you are looking for is the index of the array having highest number of votes. This index will be also useful to get the *candidateName* having highest number of vote. So, to get that index simply use the maximum value you got from this line :

```
int max = numOfVotes.Max();
```

and then use ***IndexOf*** static method to find the index of max in your array. For that try this line of code :

```
int index = Array.IndexOf<int>(numOfVotes, max);
```

Now simply print out the candidateName and highest number of votes as below :

```
Console.WriteLine(candidateName[index] + " has highest number of vote : " + numOfVotes[index] );
```

You can have a clean conception about ***Array.IndexOf()*** from [***DotNetPerls***](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-indexof) and [***MSDN***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)