# How can I find greatest number in array of number

Tags: c#

I have an array like this

```
int[] intnumber = new int[]{10,25,12,36,100,54,68,75,63,24,1,6,9,5};
```

I want to find the greatest number and make it In order from largest to smallest

like this
100,75,68,63,54,36,25,24,12,10,9,6,5,1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# find highest array value and index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to sort array in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order)

Comment: So basically you want to sort descending. Your title should say that. And I cannot believe that you didn't find any helpful resources for that.

Comment: I can find Greatest Number but I can't make it In order from largest Number to smallest Number

Comment: I don't have time to search in the net for the answer and as you know when you ask question here ,people will help you as soon as they can

Comment: but I don't know why always my score is -2 or -3 or -4

Comment: Your score is so bad because people here have better things to do than help ungrateful lazy people that can't be bothered to use the search function of SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] intnumber = new int[] { 10, 25, 12, 36, 100, 54, 68, 75, 63, 24, 1, 6, 9, 5 };
int maxValue = intnumber.Max();
```

You can sort the array for viewing elements in ascending order

```
Array.Sort(intnumber);
Array.Reverse(intnumber);
foreach (var str in intnumber )
{
    MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
}
```

Comment: *find the greatest number and make it In order from largest to smallest* So i hope he is looking for a sorting in descending, It will be better if you Include that too

Answer (score 0):

```
 exactly output that you want.

   int[] intnumber = new int[] { 10,25,12,36,100,54,68,75,63,24,1,6,9,5 };
            Array.Sort<int>(intnumber ,
                            new Comparison<int>(
                                    (i1, i2) => i2.CompareTo(i1)
                            ));
                        intnumber .Dump();
```

P.S. To run this demo you need to follow these steps:

1.Download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?LINQPad4Setup.exe).

2.Download the [demo](http://share.linqpad.net/hp52hb.linq) file, open it with LINQPad and hit F5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
int[] intnumber = new int[]{10,25,12,36,100,54,68,75,63,24,1,6,9,5};

Array.Sort(intnumber );

Array.Reverse(intnumber );

int max = intnumber[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        int[] intnumber = new int[] { 10, 25, 12, 36, 100, 54, 68, 75, 63, 24, 1, 6, 9, 5 };
        //Maximum Value
        int maxValue = intnumber.Max();
        //Maximum Index
        int maxIndex = intnumber.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with your helps

```
            Console.WriteLine("How many Numbers Do you want? ");
        int counter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] numbers = new double[counter];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((i + 1) + " : ");
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________________________");
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        Array.Reverse(numbers);
        foreach (double item in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("The Greatest Number is " + numbers[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `intNumbers` be the array that you are using, Then you can use the `.Max()` method of the Array Class to get the maximum value, that is the greatest number. If you want to Sort the Current array means You have to use the `.Sort()` method. The requirement is simply Printing the Array in descending order means you have to use the `.OrderBy()`

```
int[] inputNumbers = new int[] { 15, 12, 11, 23, 45, 21, 2, 6, 85, 1 };
Console.WriteLine("Input Array is              : {0}\n",String.Join(",",inputNumbers.OrderByDescending(x=>x)));
Console.WriteLine("Max value in the array is   : {0}\n",inputNumbers.Max());
Console.WriteLine("Array in descending order   : {0}\n",String.Join(",",inputNumbers.OrderByDescending(x=>x)));
```

Here is a [working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UonMQM)

Answer (score -1):

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int i =0;  i < intnumber.length; i++)
{    
   int num = intnumber[i];

   //Check to see if num > max.   If yes, then max = num.   
}

System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: Is it Java Language Programming Code?