# How to get the element of array with Max Value?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to get the letter of an array that as a max value of a repeated letters on a string.

I have is this:

```
var AsciiCode = new int[255];
string word= "Hello everybody";
foreach (char c in word)
{
   AsciiCode[c]++;
}

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The max count is: 
         {0}\nLetter: {1}", AsciiCode.Max(), AsciiCode.ElementAt(//MAX_VALUE_HERE//) ));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# find highest array value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Comment: Feels like a school assignment

Answer (score 1):

A solution with using Linq can be this:

```
var res =
    word.GroupBy(g => g)
        .Select(c => new { c.Key, Count = c.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

[C# Demo](http://rextester.com/OMCR16559)