# How to find the maximum possible sum from any two elements in an array

Tags: c#-4.0

The array elements are

```
int[] a = {7,5,8,9,-10,34,-150,60}
```

What is the code to find the maximum possible sum of any two elements from the above array?

Comment: The "highest sum"? Did you mean the max value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# find highest array value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Comment: I want the maximum value with the given elements

Comment: @sairamsagar: have you tried `a.Max()`?

Comment: I can't see any sum, please clarify your question: do you just want the largest array element? Or do you define some sort of element-dependent sums with some of the array elements, and you want to find the largest of them?

Comment: It is not the maximum value i want i require the sum of any two elements which give the maximum value

Comment: Edited the question....

Comment: We have to add any two elements from the given array and give the maximum sum as answer

Comment: yes the answer should be 94

Comment: lots of ways. Heck, you could bubble sort the array and just grab the top two. You want a more efficient way, do two passes - one for the max, and one for the max that isn't the previous max. What code have you *tried*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq :

```
    a.OrderByDescending(z=>z).Take(2).Sum()
```

Comment: After OP had changed the question completely you answer works ;-)

Comment: i just saw his question in comment ;)

Comment: It worked. Can I also know which two numbers produced this result

Comment: @sairamsagar: store it in a collection: `var twoHighest=a.OrderByDescending(z=>z).Take(2).ToList(); int maxSum=twoHighest.Sum();`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below way and it worked

```
int[] a = new int[10] { 10, 34, 56, -150, -200, 49, 63, 108, -94, -84 };
int[] result = a.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(result[0]+" + "+result[1]+" = "+(int)(result[0]+result[1]));
```

108 + 63 = 171
Press any key to continue . . .