# C# getting top 5 largest values from array (without LINQ)

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Just posted this code for people that may need it. Because I cannot post the whole code.

[image: Image link]

Comment: Please add your code as text - not an image

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "top five"? Do you mean the top highest numbers in an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# find highest array value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question. Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions and get answers - if you want to post code that you've found useful, I'd suggest creating a blog instead. Alternatively, you could ask a question and then post the code as a *solution*.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid LINQ?

Comment: Just posted code that would help beginners like me.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `array` contains your values:

```
var array = new List<int>() {33,55}; // fill the array as above
var result = array.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(5);
```

Also works for

```
var array = new int[] { 33, 55 }; // fill the array as above
```

Lists are preferred to arrays where possible.

Comment: Title was changed after I posted this!