# I need to find the max value in a array with C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with five countries and some medals. The last column is the total and i need to return the country with most medals. My code is "working" as long as there are no two countries with the same number of medals and those being the max number.
Problably i just don't have enough experience with arrays, but how can i return more than one contry, if i need?

```
string [,] medals = new string[5, 5];

        Random rdn = new Random();

        medals[0, 0] = "Brazil";
        medals[1, 0] = "USA";
        medals[2, 0] = "Russia";
        medals[3, 0] = "France";
        medals[4, 0] = "Egypt";

        for (int i = 0; i < medals.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < medals.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //This fills the gold, silver and copper medals
                if (j < medals.GetLength(1)-1)
                    medals[i, j] = rdn.Next(1, 6).ToString();
                else
                    //This fills the total medals
                    medals[i, j] = (int.Parse(medals[i, 1]) + int.Parse(medals[i,2]) + int.Parse(medals[i,3])).ToString();
            }

        //The first index stores the max number so far and the second stores the name of the country
        string [] winner = { "0", "0" };

        for (int i = 0; i < medals.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (int.Parse(medals[i,4]) > int.Parse(winner[0]))
            {
                winner[0] = medals[i, 4];
                winner[1] = medals[i, 0];
            }
        }
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using an array for this and not a dictionary?

Comment: try with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index/13755054

Comment: raBinn: i actually read that question, but i couldn't find where they thought about the chance of two equal max values.

Comment: I think it's better for you ton work with list of object rather than multi dimentionnal table. You can make linq query and other stuf like ordering your list and more.
Or you need to order you table and display the firsts values if the medal count are the same

Comment: I see, there are better options, but if i REALLY want to work with multidimensional array, is it possible? I've searching for an answer for two days and i need to get through this.

Comment: Order your multidimentional table and display value while medal number of first element equal other medal number elements ?

Comment: @PabloSylar is the multidimension array an assignment enforced by a teacher or something ? because with `List` instead all the code you showed drops to 3-4 lines of code maximum and is much more readable.

Comment: Paul: I thought about ordering the table, but i assume there had to be another way of solving this problem.
Franck: It was a question in a test. I kept thinking how much easier it would be if i could use a List, but the test specified table, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list to store the winners.

```
var listWinners = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < medals.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if ((listWinners.Count() == 0)||(int.Parse(medals[i,4]) > int.Parse(listWinners.First().Value)))
    {
        listWinners.Clear();
        listWinners.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(medals[i,0],medals[i,4]));
    }

    else if (int.Parse(medals[i,4]) == int.Parse(listWinners.First().Value))
    {
    listWinners.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(medals[i,0],medals[i,4]));
    }
}
```

But I would like reiterate what has been said in the comments, it would be much better if you could use a List of Object rather than multi-dimentional array. It would increase your readability of code and make things much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That works perfectly. The matter i have now is printing the KeyValuePair values. If i try     Console.WriteLine("/nWinner: {0}", listWinners.Key) VS doesn't recognize the "Key". How do i print the values inside the KVP, please?

Comment: Remember, you now "could" have more than one members. So you need to loop through the collection and print each of them. You would need to do foreach(var item in listWinners)
 Console.WriteLine("Winner: {0}, Medals : {1}", item.Key,item.Value) ;

Comment: Duly noted! Thank you ever so much for taking the time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary would be a much easier starting place. You could then just sort based on the values in the dict and use a simple loop to check for duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things I would do differently than you, but that's besides the point (see note at the end). Your issue is how to deal with the situation where you have multiple countries with equal and max number of medals.

> How to return multiple countries?

Well, that's easy: imagine you return the winner from the below function:

```
string[] GetWinner() {
    // your code
    return new[] { "20", "USA" };
}
```

Then there is no change in the data type, simply add another country to the array and the calling code should check how many you have

```
string[] GetWinner() {
    // your code
    return new[] { "20", "USA", "CAN" };
}
```

Now if you have a problem as to how to create an array whose size is unknown while creating it, then the usual solution is to use `List<>`, which in this case will act as a re-sizable array for you.

The final code would look something like below

```
static string[]  GetWinner(string[,]  medals) {

    int rows = medals.GetLength(0);

    var winners = new List<string>();
    int maxMedals = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var n = int.Parse(medals[i, 4]);
        maxMedals = n > maxMedals ? n : maxMedals;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var n = int.Parse(medals[i, 4]);
        if (n == maxMedals)
            winners.Add(medals[i, 0]);
    }

    winners.Insert(0, maxMedals.ToString());

    return winners.ToArray();
}
```

Now, I would advise you to use a better data structure to store your medals. But since I don't know the full situation, I would guess, something like below is reasonable. Instead of using named types, you can use ValueTuple - to make the code concise, if the code related to these objects are restricted to a small area of a the code file. This should avoid allocating big chunk of memory associated with 2D arrays, and also storing of int in string.

```
public class CountryMedalTally {
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string[] Medals { get; set; }
    public int MedalCount { get; set; }
}

public class Winner {
    public List<string> Country { get; set; }
    public int MedalCount { get; set; }
}

List<CountryMedalTally> AllMedals;
```