# How to get the highest value from a json response in c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a json response that I'm trying to retrieve the highest value from. I'm not sure how I would retrieve this but the value that I'm looking to get is 1.215.163.20210428-232414. How can I retrieve this value? Thanks in advance

```
 string json = "{\"availableVersions\":[\"1.205.163.20201201-130524\",\"1.215.163.20210428-232414\",\"1.211.144.20210305-115326\",\"1.207.226.20210113-194807\"]}";
 var myCleanJsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# find highest array value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order them

```
var arr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(json);
string highest = arr.OrderBy(x=>x).Last();
```